# Javascript why can't i use an array like this and how can i access the array with a calculated number

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var nodesXY = ['15% 15%','30% 16%','19% 42%','39% 80%',];
var number  = ["0","1","2","3","4","0","0","0"];

//some loop
    AccesNodes(number[1]);

function AccesNodes(number){
        console.log(number);
        //number = number;
        var firstNode = nodesXY[number];
        console.log(nodesXY[number]);
        console.log(firstNode);
        number++;
        var secondNode = nodesXY[number];
        console.log(nodesXY[number]);
        console.log(secondNode);
        number = number + 4;
        var secondNode = nodesXY[number];
        console.log(nodesXY[number]);
        console.log(secondNode);
    }
```

I don't get an `undefined` when I log the `firstNode` however when I calculate the number into "the next node" and try to get `var secondNode = nodesXY[number+1];` I get an undefined. Why won't this work?
Is there any other way to get this? I've searched all over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array `number` contains elements of type `string`. Even though JavaScript is not type-strong, variables and elements still contain data of some specific type.

When you access `number[X]`, it will therefore return a string. In order to make it work, you'll have to create an array of numbers: `var number = [1,2,3,...]` or parse the string returned from the array into a number using `parseInt(number[X])`.

For a list of the different types a JavaScript `var` can hold, see [this page](http://Your%20array%20%60number%60%20contains%20elements%20of%20type%20%60string%60.%20Even%20though%20JavaScript%20is%20not%20type-strong,%20variables%20and%20elements%20still%20contain%20data%20of%20some%20specific%20type.%20%20When%20you%20access%20%60number[X]%60,%20it%20will%20therefore%20return%20a%20string.%20In%20order%20to%20make%20it%20work,%20you'll%20have%20to%20create%20an%20array%20of%20numbers:%20%60var%20number%20=%20[1,2,3,...]%60%20or%20parse%20the%20string%20returned%20from%20the%20array%20into%20a%20number%20using%20%60parseInt(number[X])%60.%20%20For%20a%20list%20of%20the) in the MDN JavaScript documentation.

Comment: I fixed it in the first comment but this cleared a lot up for me thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Use numbers in your number array, not strings

```
var number  = [0,1,2,3,4,0,0,0];
```

Comment: there is a reason i'm using string because im getting an id's from my HTML file which are named #post1 #post2 and i split the number. And after the first comment I used parseInt to number so it worked. but thanks I probably should use my context but my script right now would take to much space to post.

Answer (score 1):

Your numbers array contains strings not actual numbers `"1" + 1` will yield `"11"` instead of `2` which isn't a key in your array. Either use `number = [0,1,...]` or use `parseInt(number) + 1`.

Comment: Thanks it worked it's so stupid i didn't think of it. I looked right passed it!